# Rails access and save foreign key value inside model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, rails-models

I have two models, `Job` and `Survey`. I am using the PaperTrail gem to track changes that occur on the models, and I want to save the `job_id` onto the version every time it’s created.

```
# app/models/job.rb

class Job < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_paper_trail :ignore => [:id, :created_at, :updated_at],
                  :meta => { :resource_id => self.id }

  has_one :survey

end

# app/models/survey.rb

class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_paper_trail :ignore => [:id, :created_at, :updated_at],
                  :meta => { :resource_id => self.job_id }

  belongs_to :job

end

# app/db/schema.db

# versions
create_table "versions", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "item_type",      null: false
  t.integer  "item_id",        null: false
  t.string   "event",          null: false
  t.string   "whodunnit"
  t.text     "object"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.text     "object_changes"
  t.integer  "resource_id"
end

# surveys
create_table "surveys", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "survey"
  t.integer  "job_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

When I run this code and try to save a new record, I get the following error:

```
undefined method `job_id' for #<Class:0x007fd53d70c0a0>
```

How do I correctly fetch the foreign `job_id` key from inside my `Survey` model?

Comment: What are the fields you have in your `versions` table? Also please post your complete error stacktrace.

Comment: Which rails version  you are using?

Comment: I’m using Rails 4.2.1

Comment: Did you tried giving `:job_id` instead of `self.job_id`?

Comment: That worked! How is it that it works when passed in as a symbol?

Comment: No idea. Its just a guess. Any ways Glad it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using `:job_id` instead of `self.job_id`.